# Prediction after Boxcox model in Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to match the predict option after `boxcox` in Stata 13 with my code using the steps described in Stata [manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rboxcoxpostestimation.pdf) (page 5).

Following is the sample code I used:

```
sysuse auto,clear
local indepvar weight foreign length  
qui boxcox price `indepvar' ,model(lhsonly)lrtest
qui predict yhat1 
qui predict resid1, residuals


//yhat2 and resid2 computed using the procedure described in Stata manual
set more off
set type double
mat coef=e(b)
local nosvar=colsof(coef)-2

qui gen constant=1
local varname weight foreign length  constant
local coefname weight foreign length  _cons

//step 1: compute residuals first
forvalues k = 1/`nosvar'{
local varname1 : word `k' of `varname'
local coefname1 : word `k' of `coefname'
qui gen xb`varname1'=`varname1'*_b[`coefname1']
}
qui egen xb=rowtotal(xb*)
qui gen resid=(price^(_b[theta:_cons]))-xb

//step 2: compute predicted value

qui gen yhat2=.
local noobs=_N
local theta=_b[theta:_cons]
forvalues j=1/`noobs'{
qui gen temp`j'=.
forvalues i=1/`noobs'{
qui replace temp`j'=((`theta'*(xb[`j']+resid[`i']))+1)^(1/`theta') if _n==`i'
}
qui sum temp`j'
local tempmean`j'=r(mean)
qui replace yhat2=`tempmean`j'' if _n==`j'
drop temp`j' 
}
drop resid
qui gen double resid2=price-yhat2



 sum yhat* resid*

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
       yhat1 |        74    6254.224    2705.175   3428.361   21982.45
       yhat2 |        74    1.000035    8.13e-06   1.000015   1.000054
      resid1 |        74   -88.96723    2094.162  -10485.45   6980.013
      resid2 |        74    6164.257    2949.496       3290      15905
```

Note: yhat1 and resid1 are based on Stata `predict`, while yhat2 and resid2 are based on my sample code. The comparison is needed to make sure the marginal effect I computed is correct (`margins` doesn't compute the marginal effect after `boxcox`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of the first residual is wrong, because you missed the definition of  y^(\lambda) on page 3 of the Manual. See also the Methods and Formulas section in the Manual entry for **boxcox** itself.

Translated to your problem, in the line

```
 qui gen resid=(price^(_b[theta:_cons]))-xb
```

the term

```
 price^(_b[theta:_cons])
```

should be:

```
 (price^(_b[theta:_cons])-1)/_b[theta:_cons]
```